# Django. Handle error in atomic block. TransactionManagementError

Tags: python, django

I want catch and handle `IntegrityError` in atomic block and continue to execute my code. For example:

```
@transaction.atomic()
def parent_func():
    try:
        child_func()
        another_child_func()
    except Exception as e:
        self.stderr.write('Cannot save: %s' % str(e))
        transaction.rollback()
    else:
        transaction.commit()

def child_func():
    a = ClassA()
    try:
        a.save()
        return a
    except (IntegrityError, ValidationError) as e:
        self.stderr.write('Cannot save "%s": %s' % (a, str(e)))
        return None

def another_child_func():
    b = ClassB()
    b.save()
    return b
```

After as I handled exception in function `child_func` I catch exception in function `another_child_func`.

Here is message of the exception:

> django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in
>   the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of
>   the 'atomic' block.

I'd like to know what possibility exists for handling an exception in an atomic block.

Comment: This is described in [Avoid catching exceptions inside atomic!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly).

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks. It helped me.